# Communication between service and app - RESTful?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I am generating an app that would communicate with a service and show the service status in the taskbar.  To do this communication, I am thinking of using RESTful WCF services.  However, my question is, since REST would have to expose a port, is there a more efficient/secure way to do this?  I am assuming the app and service will be on the same machine or possibly within the same LAN/ Active Directory domain.

Comment: this statement isn't true "since REST would have to expose a port", you can serve a restful web service through port 80, why not using service stack or web api and host it in IIS?

Comment: Port 80 is a port....

Comment: yes it's a port, but it sounds like to want to expose the restful API using a different port, look at your rest API like any other website